# SQL Server Database Size much higher than the backup size after restore

Tags: sql-server, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a .bak so much smaller than the database it's a backup of?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3694/why-is-a-bak-so-much-smaller-than-the-database-its-a-backup-of)

The database backup size is around 120 MB but when I run Restore FileListOnly, I see that the data file size is 206 MB and the Log file size is 19.8 GB. I also ran Restore HeaderOnly to check to see if its a compressed backup but its not.

So why does to restore the database needs around 20 GB space where as the .bak file is just 120 MB? and when the database backup file doesn't seem like its compressed.

Here are few details:

From FILELISTONLY

```
Type Size         BackupSize
D    206569472    118489088
L    19816644608  0
```

From HEADERONLY

```
BackupType    Compressed    BackupSize      CompressedBackupSize
1             0             119113728       119113728
```

Recovery model is simple and only one out of 539 vlfs is active after the restore

Comment: Please don't post the same question on multiple SE sites. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509345/sql-server-database-size-much-higher-than-the-backup-size-after-restore

Comment: The answer is right there in the question - the MDF/LDF size combines to 20GB but the log is 99% of that, and only about 0.2% of the log is being used (assuming all the VLFs are similarly sized). Basically, 99.8% of that 19.8GB log is empty space, hence why the backup is so much smaller than the database.

Comment: yes someone in comments suggested i post question in dba site. Not sure how to close/delete the question on stackoverflow. When I think about it the answer is pretty simple as Simon put it. Lets say a big table of 9 GB is dropped from a database with data file of 10GB. This space wont be reclaimed so my understanding was that when we backup the database the backup file will roughly be the same size as before dropping the table. So empty space in data file gets handled differently than empty space in log file?